# Somehow this method deletes my file content but for no apparent reason

Tags: java, file, io

If I didn't miss anything you should be able to run this code, just need a trace.log file in your project root folder.

I don't get what's happening. I just declare some readers / writers and try to read from the file. I get an instant null and the file seems to be empty. WHY?!

```
import java.io.*;


public class StubLogHandler {

    private String name = "";
    private String path = "";



    public StubLogHandler (String filePath, String fileName) {
        this.name = fileName;
        this.path = filePath;
    }



    // THIS IS THE PESCKY BUGGER
    public void testReadWrite() {
        this.fixPath();
        File file = new File (this.path+this.name);

        try (   FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);) {


            System.out.println("Works, I think.");
            String line = "";

            while (line != null) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                // Should get a coupl'a lines, instead I get instant null
                // Before you ask, no, the file is not initially empty
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Could not read or write to file");
        }

    }


    private void fixPath () {
        if (this.path.isEmpty())
            return;
        char lastChar = this.path.charAt(this.path.length()-1);
        if (lastChar != '\\')
            this.path += "\\";  // In case user forgets the final '\'
    }

    public String getAbsolutePath() {
        this.fixPath();
        return new File(this.path+this.name).getAbsolutePath();
    }




}


public class Start {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Start.testStuff();

    }

    private static void testStuff() {
        StubLogHandler log = new StubLogHandler("","trace.log");
        System.out.println(log.getPath()+log.getName());
        System.out.println(log.getAbsolutePath());
        log.testReadWrite();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Output:

trace.log

D:\Personal\Java\Workspaces\Default\Practice\trace.log

Works, I think.

null

Comment: Start the debugger. Walk through your code line by line to see which one deletes your file. Also, when you post on Stack Exchange, you should post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To do that, you need to first find out yourself which lines of code are causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating that writer:

```
    try (   FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file); // here
```

will immediately truncate that file in preparation for writing. e.g.

```
File x = new File("X");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(x);
```

will immediately erase the contents of the pre-existing file `X`

Comment: That is interesting behavior. I should read up on it, for the moment is there a way to prevent this "feature" ?

Comment: Don't write to it. I don't understand what you really want to ahppen, but opening a writer on a file that you're reading from will likely cause you issues

Comment: @Kalec you want to set your FileWriter to append mode. `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);`. It's still a bad idea to read and write to a file at the same time.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm testing. Sure I could read the whole documentation, but I think that's a bit too much. Trying to play with things. For example: Can I both read and write to a file, will this cause problems, is there strange behavior ? For example I don't get what's happening here. Why is it deleting ? Does close() call flush()? and because the writer is empty it completely delete all content ?

Comment: "Sure I could read the whole documentation". That would probably be a good idea. Note my amended answer re. *opening* the file writer

Comment: Yes, I know you are completely right. But reading the whole documentation from top to bottom is just not the way to learn anything this large (not talking just about java.io, but java in general). I find that playing with stuff is way better. Now true, if I had suspected the writer to be the issue, i could quickly jump to the documentation, but I did not suspect it (even though I should have).

Comment: @Kalec You don't need to read the entire documentation for `FileWriter`. You *do* need to narrow the problem down to a single block of code and read the documentation on just the stuff in that block that looks like it might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Normal reading and separately writing to the same file does not work.

FileReader and FileWriter are already buffered I believe. I personally do not use them, as they use the default platform encoding, which is gives unportable data.

And then the end of file is indicated by readLine returning null, hence do:

```
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            // Should get a coupl'a lines, instead I get instant null
            // Before you ask, no, the file is not initially empty
        }
```

Maybe be you want do something like:

```
Path fpath = Paths.get(this.path+this.name);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(fpath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
... process the lines
Files.write(fpath, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: This is quite intriguing. I am completely overwhelmed by the abundance of IO classes java has (not to mention the horrible api). Is the `Path` / `Paths` (ohhh that's bad api design) combined with `Files.readAllLines` considered a better approach ?

Comment: Java till version 7 retained providing Files and Path/Paths with such goodies.